# How to correctly implement recursion for QuickSort in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm currently working on QuickSort in Java, and I've successfully sorted the list for the first iteration. Nonetheless, my recursion implementation is not doing what I want. What can be the reason for that?

**The list is [11, 4, 53, 65, 44, 23, 202, 37, 1]**

```
...
quickSort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
...

public static List<Integer> quickSort(List<Integer> l1, int from, int to) {
        if (l1.size() < 2)
            return l1;
        int pivot = l1.get(to);
        int counterLastSwapPos = 0;
        int counter = from;
        while (counter < l1.indexOf(pivot)) {
            if (l1.get(counter) >= pivot)
                counter++;
            else {
                int temp = l1.get(counter);
                l1.set(counter, l1.get(counterLastSwapPos));
                l1.set(counterLastSwapPos, temp);
                counterLastSwapPos++;
            }
            System.out.println(l1);
        }
        quickSort(l1, 0, l1.indexOf(pivot));
        quickSort(l1, l1.indexOf(pivot) + 1, l1.size());
        return l1;
    }
```

Comment: By the way, you should either choose your pivot randomly or keep it right in the middle of `from` and `to`, rather than putting it at the end (`to`)

Comment: @user really? What can you say about this explanation video ?https://youtu.be/ZHVk2blR45Q?t=507

Comment: @user I tried with sublists already, but then how will I add them all up together? I wanted to manipulate the original list only so I don't have to think about how to connect the sorted list like in Merge Sort e.g.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that video doesn't seem to be using the same algorithm that you are, as far as I can see. See this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

Comment: @user but Java will complain saying it lacks one parameter. I can override this method if this will solve the issue. What do you reckon?

Comment: What do you mean? Is it here? `quickSort(l1, 0, l1.indexOf(pivot));
        quickSort(l1, l1.indexOf(pivot) + 1, l1.size());` If so, do this `quickSort(l1, from, l1.indexOf(pivot));
        quickSort(l1, l1.indexOf(pivot) + 1, to);`

Comment: @user the sublist worked actually. Check the implementation in the answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214546/discussion-between-jj-kam-and-user).

Answer (score 1):

Here is **the correct implementation** of Quicksort In-Place in Java (ascending order).

```
 public static List<Integer> quickSort(List<Integer> l1, int from, int to) {
        System.out.println("Quick Sort \n");

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //select a pivot - the last element of the list
        int pivot = l1.get(to - 1);
        //introduce two counters:
        int counterLastSwapPos = 0;//this first one will track the index of the element
        //that is bigger than the pivot - we start from zero (we never actually
        // know that this number is actually bigger - it is a
        // presupposition)
        for (int counter = 0; counter < l1.indexOf(pivot); counter++) {
            //we also have a counter to track our position during the iteration
            //if the element at the current position is smaller than the pivot
            //swap the element(current position) with the element that is bigger
            //than the pivot.
            if (l1.get(counter) < pivot) {
                int temp = l1.get(counter);
                l1.set(counter, l1.get(counterLastSwapPos));
                l1.set(counterLastSwapPos, temp);
                //Once the swap has happened - increment the counter
                //that tracks the number bigger than the pivot
                counterLastSwapPos++;
                //finally, in the loop, the position counter will be
                //automatically incremented
            }
            //when the position counter reaches the last allowed position,
            //swap the pivot with the the counter that tracks
            // the number bigger than the pivot
            if (counter == l1.indexOf(pivot) - 1) {
                l1.set(l1.indexOf(pivot), l1.get(counterLastSwapPos));
                l1.set(counterLastSwapPos, pivot);
            }
        }
        //as this sorting is a "Divide&Conquer" type, we use recursion to perform
        //the same operations on two parts of the list. That is why, (if you scroll up),
        //you'll see that once the list becomes size of 1, the recursion will stop.
        //Our pivot is now somewhere in the middle - this was our aim.
        //Now, pay attention to perform the recursion on
        //two lists that WILL NOT include the pivot itself
        if (from < l1.indexOf(pivot)) quickSort(l1, from, l1.indexOf(pivot));
        if (l1.indexOf(pivot) + 1 < to) quickSort(l1, l1.indexOf(pivot) + 1, to);
        //list is sorted
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println("Time: " + duration + "\n");

        return l1;
    }
```